# How do you iterate over and retrieve values from a hash with arrays?

Tags: ruby, json, api

I am trying to build a quick hack that "likes" all the recent photos on instagram of a particular tag.

I have authenticated and used the JSON gem to turn the JSON from the API into a Ruby Hash like this:

```
def get_content (tag_name)

   uri = URI.parse("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/#{tag_name}/media/recent? access_token=#{@api_token}")

   http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
   http.use_ssl = true
   http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

   request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

   json_output = http.request(request)
   @tags = JSON.parse(json_output.body)

end
```

This outputs a hash with arrays as keys nested like the original JSON ( ex. `http://instagr.am/developer/endpoints/tags/`)

I am trying to iterate over and retrieve all the "id"s of the photos.

However when I use each method:

```
@tags.each do |item| 
  puts item["id"]
end
```

I get an error:

```
instagram.rb:23:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
from instagram.rb:23:in `block in like_content'
from instagram.rb:22:in `each'
from instagram.rb:22:in `like_content'
from instagram.rb:42:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you sure the data is what you think it is? Looks like you might be making an assumption about types that isn't correct.

Comment: Try `p @tags.class, @tags` for more insight on what `@tags` turned out to be.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> instagram.rb:23:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
> ```

You're getting this error because in `puts item["id"]`, `item` is an Array, not a Hash, so Ruby tries to convert what you put between `[]` into an integer index, but it can't because it's a string (`"id"`).

This arises from the fact that `json_output.body` is a Hash. Take a second look at the example JSON response in the documentation:

```js
{ "data" : [
    { "type"     : "image",
      // ...
      "id"       : "22699663",
      "location" : null
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

This whole structure becomes a single Hash with one key, `"data"`, so when you call `@tags.each` you're actually calling `Hash#each`, and since `"data"`'s value is an Array when you call `item["id"]` you're calling `Array#[]` with the wrong kind of parameter.

Long story short, what you actually want to do is probably this:

```ruby
@tags = JSON.parse( json_output.body )[ "data" ]
```

..then `@tags` will be the Array you want instead of a Hash and you can iterate over its members like you wanted:

```ruby
@tags.each do |item| 
  puts item["id"]
end
```

Comment: well explained. Many Thanks. Solved my purpose.